# Spring pageable cache key for each page

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-cache

I am trying to do something like following

```
@Cacheable(value = ACTIVE_DATA_CONFIGURATION_CACHE, key = "#tenant.id.concat('-').concat(#pageable.page)")
    public Page<DataConfiguration> findAllByTenant(final Pageable pageable, final Tenant tenant) {
    }
```

exception

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'page' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case try using `KeyGenerator`

```
@Cacheable(value = "doOneThing", keyGenerator = "CustomGenerator")
```

Something like this:

```
public class CustomGenerator implements KeyGenerator {

 public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
    String code = "UNIQUE_CODE"; // implements logic from params
    return code;
 }

}
```

Comment: Can i get pageable argument in key generator

Comment: Yes, it is in Object... params

Answer (score 2):

As Pageable does not have a property page, if you are trying to generate a key as `{tenant.id}-{pageNumber}`, you can change the key value to `#tenant.id.concat('-').concat(#pageable.pageNumber)`.